# Bootstrap Tour Return To Top When End Pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I am using the following code in a Bootstrap tour to try capture the user pressing the end tour button, when this is pressed I want the user to be returned to the top of the screen. Right now my code will run when the new "popover" loads instead of clicking the end tour button. Is there any way of doing this? I have tried changing the code to be fully in HTML e.g '"+End()+"' to 'End()' but this also does not work.

```
(function(){
        var tour = new Tour({
    steps: [
          {
        element: ".tour-step.tour-step-four",
        placement: "right",
        title: "What is a marker",
        content: "The marker is a QR code which you can print out, or embed on a web page. To access and view the AR content, users can scan the marker with a QR code scanner on their smartphones."
      },
          {
        element: ".tour-step.tour-step-five",
        placement: "right",
        title: "Accessing content without a marker",
        content: "You can link directly to the AR Project so users can access the content without using a QR code scanner. You will still need to print out, or embed the marker on a web page so users can view the content."
      }
    ],
        template: function () {
        return (
            tour.getCurrentStep() === 4 
                ? "<div class='popover tour'>" + 
                    "<div class='arrow'></div>" +
                    "<h3 class='popover-title'></h3>" +
                    "<div class='popover-content'></div>" +
                    "<div class='popover-navigation'>" +
                        "<button class='btn btn-default' data-role='prev'>« Prev</button>" +
                        "<span data-role='separator'> </span>" +
                        "<button onclick='"+End()+"' class='btn btn-default' data-role='end'>End tour</button>" +
                    "</div>" +
                "</div>"
                : "<div class='popover tour'>" + 
                    "<div class='arrow'></div>" +
                    "<h3 class='popover-title'></h3>" +
                    "<h3 class='test'>"+tour.getCurrentStep()+"</h3>" +
                    "<div class='popover-content'></div>" +
                    "<div class='popover-navigation'>" +
                        "<button class='btn btn-default' data-role='prev'>« Prev</button>" +
                        "<span data-role='separator'> </span>" +
                        "<button class='btn btn-default' data-role='next'>Next »</button>" +
                        "<button onclick='"+End()+"' class='btn btn-default' data-role='end'>End tour</button>" +
                    "</div>" +
                "</div>"
        );
    },
});
 function End() {
 console.log("test post");
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
}
 $("#start-tour").click(function(){
    tour.init();
    tour.start();
    tour.restart();
});
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this myself, changing

```
<button onclick='"+End()+"' class='btn btn-default' data-role='end'>End tour</button>
```

to

```
<button class='btn btn-default click_me' data-role='end'>End tour</button>.
```

Instead of the `end()` function I added the following code:

```
  $(document).on("click", ".click_me", function() {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
});
```